# How to dynamically add items in Drawer Navigator in react native?

Tags: react-native

I wan to add Routes into my drawer navigator from an api respones. 
It looks like this :

```
componentDidMount() {
    let steps = [
        { 
            "commonName" : "Input Configuration",
            "compname" : "InputConfig"
        },
        {
            "commonName" : "Dashboard",
            "compname" : "Dashboard"
        }
    ]
```

Where commonName is the name of the route and compname is the name of corresponding component name. 
How to add these items into Drawer Navigator?

Answer (score 0):

I would keep `steps` as an initial state variable, and as API responses come in, call `this.setState(change steps here)`. It's a little difficult to say how exactly to implement that without more information on where your API calls are happening and if you're receiving the data in the same class, but that is the general process. Set the state, and set up your component to use that state, and as the state needs to change, call `setState`.

If you are using redux its a little easier.